# Is it possible to add a hyperlink to an icon or picture in Excel?

Tags: excel, image, hyperlink, reference, icons

I have a formula for a hyperlink in excel which refers to the first empty cell in a table where I can add new values.
The formula is as follows:
=HYPERLINK("#"&CELL("address",INDEX(Running[Date],MATCH(9.99E+307,Running[Date])+1)),"New Run")

I want to have an icon as a button to direct me to this place. I could not add this as a hyperlink to the icon, should I use VBA code to use the hyperlink?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Change your formula to

`=INDEX(Running[Date],MATCH(9.99E+307,Running[Date])+1)`

and save it as a Defined Name, e.g. MyHyperlink.

Then right-click on the shape and select *Link/Existing File or Web Page* and in the *Address* box put:

`#MyHyperlink`